# Replicate plotly interactive plot example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, r, plot

I am trying to replicate the following example from the plotly website. https://plot.ly/r/click-events/. I have copied the html and the js into separate files in the same directory and added the following line to the top of the html:

```
<head>
<script src="interactiveplot.js"></script>
</head>
```

where interactiveplot.js is the name of the file containing the javascript from the example. When I open the html file in chrome the data point selecting functionality does not work. Please let me know if you can reproduce this functionality and what might be the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Look into `event_data()` here [https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/tree/feature/transmit](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/tree/feature/transmit). That way you wont need JS at all. You should be able to access click and selection event data directly in shiny.

Comment: I noticed this feature is only available in the future/transmit branch. How would I install this branch specifically with devtools? I have tried  devtools::install_github(repo="ropensci/plotly",ref="future/transmit") without success

Comment: use this - `devtools::install_github('ropensci/plotly@feature/transmit')`

Comment: Okay I have this working now. Thanks! I am still interested in figuring out this example though.